# How to Know if Cell is Changed in cxGrid

Tags: delphi, quantumgrid

It's been hours already and I can't figure out how to know if a cell is changed in cxGrid. loading of data is unbound, and gridview is grid table view.

What I want is cells will be edited by user, then after they're done editting the cells,
user will click a button "apply changes". "apply changes" button will now iterate every cell,
and changed cells will be processed.

Comment: If you're using a GridTableView, there is a EditChanged event that you can use. It passes in the GridTableItem that fired the event.

Comment: I think my question is not clear, I'm editing it..

Comment: The grid control does not keep track of the information you need. You need to checkpoint the values at a particular point in time, and then at some later point in time know what has changed. Either keep track of the changes, or perform a diff. The bottom line is that you have to code this functionality.